# Woocommerce reports – customer_list export to csv

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, export

I use woocommerce plugin and i need to export Wc-reports – customer_list from customer tab to csv, but Woocommerce doesn't have this option by default. Is there way to export this report by SQL-query or some code snipet in function.php? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce as this option by default.

Go to Back-Office --> WooCommerce --> Customers -> Download

[image: Clients CSV]

Comment: Thank you, I have updated Woo and now i can see this report.